# Property of 'object' is undefined with object: React.PropTypes.object

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get authentication up and running on my first real react and redux app but am stuck at managing route access and verification.

Here is my code to verify authorization:

```
export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

I am importing and calling it on my route here:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
          <Layout>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
            <Route path='/signout' component={SignOut} />
            <Route path='/brain' component={RequireAuth(Brain)} />
          </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
./src/components/auth/RequireAuth.js.__webpack_exports__.a
src/components/auth/RequireAuth.js:7
   4 | export default function(ComposedComponent) {
   5 |   class Authentication extends Component {
   6 |     static contextTypes = {
>  7 |       router: React.PropTypes.object
   8 |     }
   9 | 
  10 |     componentWillMount() {
View compiled
```

Thanks for any direction you can provide!

Comment: What version of React are you running? `React.PropTypes` has been deprecated since v15.5. It's now its own `PropTypes` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). You likely should be importing that and then using just `PropTypes.object`.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks you very much. Yes, I'm using the latest version of React and using a somewhat dated tutorial so, I figured it was an issue regarding that but couldn't find anything when searching. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Hope it helps

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: Tried it out, but no such luck! Thanks for trying though, I appreciate it.